# How to add function to the mouse right-click menu in desktop

Tags: windows

[image]

desktop: window server 2003

Assume i have a cmd.sh that echo a message, here i want to run it in anywhere , when i right click the mouse and choose the echo function.

hope for your answer, thanks

Comment: Here is my situation.
I want to create a auto-generator tool to construct files.
When in a folder, i right-click the mouse, select the generator function to run the bash script to construct a few files, which have default content.

Comment: It's off the topic for bash. What is your desktop environment? gnome/kde/unity/xfce etc? That should be the correct tag for this question. I am adding gnome tag for now. Edit if required.

Comment: That looks like a Windows screenshot to me. Plus I don't think `TortoiseSVN` runs on anything else.

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/)

Comment: Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 0):

Editing the registry as @dbvega indicates works if you always want the same menu item to appear.  This is called a static menu.  But if you want to do have more control over your menu item, such as changing the visibility, text, and icon depending on various runtime conditions, you need to create a dynamic context menu shell extension, which involves programming a COM object.  [This MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758091(v=vs.85).aspx) describes the difference.

Comment: Thank you, the [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/) helps a lot.